# How to avoid duplicate values in the output of v-for loop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to remove or filter out the duplicate values in the output of my **v-for** loop. So, that '**John**' appears only once instead of appearing twice in the output. Is that possible to do in **vuejs** ?

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
             el: "#app",
             data: function () {
                     return {
                       searchFields: ['number', 'name'],
                       search: '',
                       items: [
                               { name: 'Mary'},
                               { name: 'John'},
                               { name: 'John'},
                               { name: 'William'}
                             ]
                      };
             }
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/LkmXNY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuejs filterBy provides 3 arguments to the filter function: value of the current item, the index of the item and the whole array. Following works without a temporary array:

```
methods: {
        myFilter: function (val, idx, arr) {
          for(var i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            if(arr[i].name === val.name) {
              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        } 
      }
```

Comment: excellent solution man...this works even more perfect than the above one...because I do not need a temporary array in this case....simple awesome solution...thanks @himmet avsar...cheeers !!1

Answer (score 3):

So by checking the [filters-documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/#filterBy) you can see that you can write your own custom filters.

So by having `myFilter` you can define what you want to have in a method.

```
v-for="item in items | filterBy myFilter">
```

Now adding the method it should something like this:

```
let arr = [];

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      searchFields: ['number', 'name'],
      search: '',
      items: [
        { name: 'Mary'},
        { name: 'John'},
        { name: 'John'},
        { name: 'William'}
      ]
    };
  },
  // this is where your filter method is defined
  methods: {
    myFilter: function(val) {
      if(arr.indexOf(val.name) === -1) {
        arr.push(val.name);
        return val.name;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

What this does is check if your value is in your array `arr`. If not, it adds it to the array, preventing duplicate items appearing later on.

So only if your `item.name` hasn't been displayed already, your filter returns the name to the view.

[Check it out](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzxvBP)

*Maybe there is a nicer/easier solution to this, but good enough for now :)

Comment: hey @marczking...did u test ? your pen is not working !! it is just showing {{item.name}} in the output...check please

Comment: what do you mean? If I open the pen it displays 3 names instead of 4. It's working for me :S maybe there is an other error I'm not getting?

Comment: the search seams not be working. I'll have a look a little later

Answer (score 0):

I used a computed value, as suggested by the Vuejs guide:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

```
computed: {
    uniqueNames: function() {
      var filtered_array = [];
      for(var i =0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        if(filtered_array.indexOf(this.items[i].name) === -1) {
          filtered_array.push(this.items[i].name)
        }
      }
    return filtered_array;
    }
  }
```

With this v-for:

```
v-for="name in uniqueNames"
```

See [my codepen](https://codepen.io/roverv/pen/YQvdya)